# Spring dispatcher-servlet.xml not working properly

Tags: spring, url, dispatcher

Hi Friends I tried to run a spring sample hello world program.I am getting an error saying that "HTTP Request with /Helloworld/ page not found" actually i create new dynamic project and copy previously executed project "dispatcher-servlet.xml" file and tried to execute it but it says above error please help me and also i wrote everthing correctly

Comment: please add your code or what did you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Spring dispatcher-servlet.xml and jar files

spring,spring-webmvc,jstl,servlet-api

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean name="/welcome.htm" 
class="com.sample.controller.HelloWorldController" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```